# How to merge PDF files(generated by PowerApps Flow ) using PowerApps Automate

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I've created a flow for generating a Word template for Patient Statement, and then converting it into PDF. I'm running this flow for individual patients and the data is coming from SQL stored procedure to Word template to PDF.

These PDF files are being generated and stored over in SharePoint. Instead of 50 separate files I'm trying to merge everything into one PDF file. I didn't find appropriate action in PowerApps flow for merging all the PDFs into one.

Does anyone have an idea or suggestion regarding this? Can we achieve this using Flow in PowerApps?

Comment: You should either create one large word document and convert to pdf or download the folder they are stored in as a zip file

Answer (score 1):

Merging PDFs is not natively available in Power Automate, you have to use third party connectors to subscription services. Its not fantastic.

I suggest you follow the approach this blog outlines which uses Azure Functions. its probably the cheapest and quickest approach to solve your issue.

[Merge Pdf Files in SharePoint using An Azure Function](https://www.m365-dev.com/2020/06/21/merge-pdf-files-in-sharepoint-using-an-azure-function/)

Comment: There's a lot of premium connectors that can merge separate files if $$$ is not an issue. Adobe PDF Services Trials can receive 1000 PDF Transactions for up to 6 months.